# I am trying to make even numbers in this array equal 0, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

this is my first post on here as I am a beginner in Computer Science. I am taking college classes and want to decide if I should take on Comp Sci as a major. As my title states "I am trying to make even numbers in this array equal 0, what am I doing wrong?" I am using Python 2
Thanks in advance.

```
def main():
    arr = [4, 9, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20]
    for i in arr:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            arr[i] = 0
    print arr
```

Comment: On your first iteration `i` is equal to 4. The conditional `i%2==0` evaluates to `True` as `4` is indeed cleanly divisible by 2. Since its true we then go to the next line where we assign the value 0 to index i. `i` is still 4, so we didnt replace the zero-th element, we actually replaced the 4th which is `8`.

Comment: Running that script would have give error. Posting traceback would be good idea in future postings. And quite often reading traceback carefully helps you resolve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's print a little in Python console so you'll see your problem.

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> arr = ["a",1,"x",2,[1,2,3]]
>>> for i in arr:
...     print i
...
a
1
x
2
[1, 2, 3]
```

So for loop gives you item from list, not index.

Since this is school homework, I let you proceed from here.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

`i` is the value, and you're using it as both the value and the index. For reassigning, you really want both, so use `enumerate`:

```
for i, val in enumerate(arr):  # Produces pairs of index and value
    if val % 2 == 0:  # Test value
        arr[i] = 0    # Reassign index
```

Alternatively, you can do a bulk rebuilding of the `list` without needing the index via a list comprehension:

```
arr = [0 if val % 2 == 0 else val for val in arr]
```